# Program behaving to given conditions inconsistently for same input

Tags: java, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

This is a function of a game I made. It is a replica of the popular board game [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)).

I have replaced 8 colours with the digits 1-8. Repetition is not allowed and the computer generated code also strictly obeys these rules.

I have put conditions to give an error when the user entered code has the digits 0 or 9 in it or is not a 4 digit code.

However, the program does not always give an error to the mistake the user has performed.

For example:

1) User enters 0439.

Program gives error.

2) User enters 412906.

Program is fine with it.

And these are ***very*** ***inconsistent*** as there is a possibility that the next time you run the program, you won't get the same error for the same  input.

Can someone please help me figure out the problem?

Note: Please remove the `quit()` function code in the end as it is related to another class in my program. Just delete that last if block.

I have tried searching it but I couldn't find a question similar to my doubt and none of my friends could help me.

```
public void master()throws IOException,InterruptedException
{        
    int i,j,c=0,a,k=0;
    String str,ch;
    String code[]=new String[4];

    System.out.println("\t\t\tWelcome to Mastermind\n");
    System.out.println("\nThe computer will generate a 4 digit number consisting of digits from 1 to 8 without repetition and you will have to crack the code in 10 attempts.\n0,9,letters and special characters are not allowed and if entered,the computer will ask you to try again.\nKey description-\n □ means that a digit in the number entered by the user is present in the code but is at the wrong position.\n ■ means that a digit in the number entered by the user is present in the code and is at the correct position.\nIn both the cases,the user will not be told to which digit the key given by the computer is referring to.\nDuplicates are not allowed and are not present in the code generated by the computer.\nIf you try to enter a number with repeating digits,it will not be accepted and you will be told to try again.");
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter \"play\" to start");
    String play=in.readLine();
    if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("play"))
    {            
        code[0]=Integer.toString((int)(Math.random()*7)+1);// generates first no. of code
        do           
        {
            code[1]=Integer.toString((int)(Math.random()*7)+1);// generates second no. of code
        }while(code[1].equals(code[0]));

        do           
        {
            code[2]=Integer.toString((int)(Math.random()*7)+1);// generates third no. of code
        }while(code[2].equals(code[1]) || code[2].equals(code[0]));

        do           
        {
            code[3]=Integer.toString((int)(Math.random()*7)+1);// generates fourth no. of code
        }while(code[3].equals(code[2]) || code[3].equals(code[1]) || code[3].equals(code[0]));

        System.out.println("The game begins");
        for(a=1;a<=10;a++)
        {
            System.out.println("Attempt "+a);
            str=in.readLine();   

            if(str.length()!=4)  
            {
                System.out.println("Try again with only digits from 1 to 8 and only a 4-digit number without repetitions");
                str=in.readLine();
            }

            else
            {
                for(i=0;i<4;i++)
                {
                    c=(int)(str.charAt(i));
                    if(c>56||c<49) // checks if input is appropriate by comparing ASCII value of the input
                    {
                        System.out.println("Try again with only digits from 1 to 8 and only a 4-digit number");
                        str=in.readLine(); 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
                        {
                            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
                            {
                                if(i!=j)
                                {
                                    if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j))
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Try again with only digits from 1 to 8 and only a 4-digit number");
                                        str=in.readLine();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }  
            }

            if((code[0]+code[1]+code[2]+code[3]).equals(str))
            {
                k=1;
                break;
            }
            for(i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                ch=Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
                for(j=0;j<4;j++)
                {                        
                    if(code[j].equals(ch))
                    {
                        if(i==j) 
                        {
                            System.out.print("■");
                        }
                        else
                            System.out.print("□");
                    }                        
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        } 
        if(k!=1)
            System.out.println("The code is "+code[0]+code[1]+code[2]+code[3]);
        else
            System.out.println("You did it!!!");
    }
    System.out.println("Thank You");
    if(!play.equalsIgnoreCase("play"))
        quit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The inconsistency in your code is because of this:

```
if(str.length()!=4)  
            {
                System.out.println("Try again with only digits from 1 to 8 and only a 4-digit number without repetitions");
                str=in.readLine();
            }
```

Think about that a minute. The user is doing his first attempt with the number 412906, which is invalid. And after that, you just accept the new input without any kind of validation.

What should happen here is that the process start again with the for incremented in one (+1)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str.length()!=4)  
{
    System.out.println("Try again with only digits from 1 to 8 and only a 4-digit number without repetitions");
    str=in.readLine();
}
```

Here you check the length only once and then take another input without checking the length again, and also skip the whole part of checking the digits because you put it in an `else` clause which doesn't get executed if the first input's length wasn't 4.

This will do:

```
while(true){
    str = in.readLine();
    if(str.length() != 4){
        // wrong length detected -  print error message
        continue;
    }
    boolean wrongChars = false;
    for(char c : str.toCharArray())
        if(c>56||c<49){
            wrongChars = true;
            break;
        }
    if(wrongChars){
        // wrong characters detected - print error message
        continue;
    }
    boolean duplicateChars = false;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < 4; j++)
            if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j))
                duplicateChars = true;
    if(duplicateChars){
        // duplicate digits detected - print error message
        continue;
    }
    break; // all input checks passed - break the loop
}
```

Comment: for(char c : str.toCharArray())


Can you please explain this line? I got my mistake and the mistake is not only because of what you mentioned but also because of a similar loop in the else clause.

Comment: it is the equivalent of a `foreach()` loop in other languages such as C#, this line splits `str` into an array of `char`s and iterates through this array, in each iteration `c` is the current `char`.

Comment: I'm getting an error using your code. In the str.toCharArray statement, it tells bad initializer found.

Comment: I tried messing with it and made the code, but it is still giving errors like it just accepted 1230

Comment: Sorry but it is still inconsistent.

Comment: I just tested this code and it works perfectly fine for me. If you get the `bad initializer found` error you should change the name of the variable defined in the loop (`c`) so it doesn't have the same name as a variable outside the loop, otherwise you would be attempting to create a variable with a name of an already existing variable.

Comment: I fixed that, I agree the errors have reduced, but some of them are still there.

Comment: Can you paste the code and example inputs that the program treats incorrectly?